# Printing different results due to memory address issue? Simple C++ issue

Tags: c++, printf, cout, memory-address

I'm new to C++ and have run into a weird issue in my code. I am thinking it's related to the memory address stack but I don't know enough to resolve it / truly understand what is going on. Essentially I am getting a warning when I compile the code. Then I also observe some weird behavior where the values printed are different from within the `runnable` function and the `main` function. If anyone knows what's going on and how I can resolve this discrepancy it would be much appreciated.

**Compilation warning**

> warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable
>   'DATAPTS' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
>       return DATAPTS;

**Code excerpt**

```
static float * runnable(char *im1, char *im2)
{
    // ... SOME MATH ...

    float DATAPTS[16] = { L1A.x, L1A.y, L1B.x, L1B.y, L2A.x, L2A.y, L2B.x, L2B.y, L3A.x, L3A.y, L3B.x, L3B.y, L4A.x, L4A.y, L4B.x, L4B.y };

    for (int i = 16 - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
      cout << DATAPTS[i] << " , ";
    cout << "\n";

    return DATAPTS;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  float * res;
  res = runnable((char*)"VOLVIC LOGO.png",(char*)"IMG-0394.JPG");

  for (int i = 16 - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
      cout << res[i] << " , ";
    cout << "\n";
}
```

**Print out from runnable**

> 1413.63 , 1754.15 , 2687.39 , 1758.69 , 2687.39 , 1758.69 , 2771.43 , 3581.81 , 2771.43 , 3581.81 , 1322.25 , 3700.2 , 1322.25 , 3700.2 , 1413.63 , 1754.15 ,

**Print out from main**

> 1413.63 , -1.32203e-28 , 1.4013e-45 , 5.98634e-34 , 1.4013e-45 , 5.97362e-34 , 4.59149e-41 , -1.17931e+24 , 1.4013e-45 , 5.98634e-34 , 4.59163e-41 , -1.32203e-28 , 1.4013e-45 , 5.97655e-34 , 4.59149e-41 , -1.1793e+24 ,

Comment: You are returning address to a local variable, what do you expect to happen?Use `std::vector` and return that instead. `(char*)"VOLVIC LOGO.png"` is UB too.

Comment: You are returning a pointer to a local variable. The variable and its memory are freed once your function `runnable` returns, causing the pointer `res` in your main to point into invalid memory. Accessing it is UB.

Comment: So basically you can make `DATAPTS` be `static` itself, and you should be fine.

Comment: @DeiDei Yea, that works until it doesn't. Don't do that unless you are dealing with very low-level stuff and know what are you doing.

Comment: Making it `static` works in this case, but if I make `DATAPTS` into a `static` variable if I call `runnable` a second time on a different dataset it gives the same result as the first dataset.

Comment: @Quimby Sure, it's a quick fix. I'd argue for a return type of `std::array` while still having the local variable `static`. Might as well avoid the dynamic nature of a vector since the size is known.

Comment: @AntersBear Well, ditch the initialization, and go for assignment. That will happen no matter what.

Comment: You are right, that is a better solution here.

Comment: @DeiDei how do I do that?

Comment: @AntersBear `DATAPTS[0] = L1A.x; DATAPTS[1] = L1A.y; .......`.